# Android emulator doesn't start through xpra

Tags: android, ssh

I use xpra under linux to connect to a computer running android studio. The problem is that every time I try to run the emulator I get the following error

Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":100".

My laptop has an AMDA6-6310 with Radeon r4. I've also tried to connect with ssh -X with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Android studio must be using opengl rendering, so you will need to be using [Xdummy](http://xpra.org/trac/wiki/Xdummy) and [VirtualGL](http://xpra.org/trac/wiki/Usage/OpenGL)